# Participant Search - Failed to interpret input for search

Tags: civievent, search

In the latest version of CiviCRM on the latest stable version of Drupal 7, if I attempt the following:

- Events > Find Participants
- Enter an event name AND a participant status

The search results in an error - "Failed to interpret input for search"

This doesn't happen if you enter the event name only, or the event name and participant role. It also doesn't happen where the combination of event name and participant status results in a 'no matches found' result - it only happens when the search would generate a result.

I've done a 25 second screencast of the issue in action:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1RmpVyqxX6g99UsKLc5H9pcZtXLpCtqmG/view

Any advice gratefully received!

CiviCRM version 5.13.2, Drupal 7.67

Thank you

Comment: Hi Robin - usually worth showing you have proven this problem exists on one of the demo sites eg https://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org since if that is the case then this can then get logged as a bug. If i go to https://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org/civicrm/contact/search/advanced?reset=1 then yes i see same issue. Adding as Answer

Comment: Aha! Thanks @petednz-fuzion - will do in future :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be a bug since i can replicate at https://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org/civicrm/contact/search/advanced?reset=1

[image]

gives

Sorry, due to an error, we are unable to fulfill your request at the moment. You may want to contact your administrator or service provider with more details about what action you were performing when this occurred.

**Failed to interpret input for search**

Have mentioned in https://chat.civicrm.org/civicrm/channels/product-maintenance

Answer (score 1):

Logged here https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/issues/956 - we will include a fix for this in a 5.13 point release in the next few days

Comment: Thank you very much @eileen

Answer (score 0):

I'd just like to add that if you're specifically trying to get all participant with a specific status you need to be careful - with the workaround of searching only on the event, if you try to sort by status, it will then return all participants for all events instead of just the selected event.

I see there's a fix for the original issue in 13.3, I'm on 13.2, so we'll need to check if this secondary issue also exists after the update.

Thanks a bunch for the quick fix! :)

Comment: Confirmed the initial issue is resolved with 13.4. This second issue still exists (if you click any sort heading), but if you click search again then you get the proper results with the sort you clicked on.